# Information about Mudras

Tags: mudra

Someone know the figures or can give me some information on how to do these mudras:

chakra Mudra
chapa Mudra
laDDuka Mudra

Thank you.

Comment: Are these Mudras, specially the last one, related to Ganesha worship?

Comment: yes , indeed. but not only to Ganesha one. Strangely i cannot find them on the internet easly.

Answer (score 2):

**Chakra Mudra:**

> hastau tu sammukhau kritva sulagnau suprasaritau
> kanishthangushthakau lagnau mudraisha cakrasangika

-Kriya kanda baridhi Vol 1. Ch 8 (Mudras)

[image]

Image Credit -

Image by [Amritendu Mukhopadhyay](https://pixabay.com/users/amritendumukhopadhyay-6796874/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=7220044) from [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=7220044)